# Moving WCF to HTTPS

Tags: wcf

My http based web service is working fine and I've been asked to move it to https (the certificates and stuff on IIS have already been done).

But I'm completely stuck on what I need to do. All the websites seem to show you what changes to make to the web.config file, but when I check mine it is nothing like these (e.g. there is no services element), and none of the sites mentioned what changes to the client config you make and they're all dated from 5 years ago or more.

When I check my client config file that calls the webservice it seems to have half the configuration entries that is supposed to be in the new web.config on the server.

Can anyone help?

CLIENT config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://example.com/TestService/TestService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="Service.IMyService"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

SERVER WEB.CONFIG

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Do you have a .svc file? Is there any configuration where you define the contract for the service?

Comment: it is something like
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="MyInterface.MyService" CodeBehind="MyService.svc.cs" %>

Comment: Do you have a <services> tag somewhere in a config file on server?

Comment: No, according to MSDN regarding <services> it is an optional entry in the simplified model: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Those are the only 3 files, web.config, svc, and the client

All I want is to know what to change to support the certificates already set up.

Answer (score 0):

I changed you settings so that is similar to my settings. You should use the values that are specific for your server:

I have added

```
<security mode="Transport"></security>
```

and

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
             <serviceCertificate findValue="<thumbprint>" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
             storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>
```

this is needed for specifying the certificate and that is should use transport security mode.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

         <security mode="Transport"></security>

        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
             <serviceCertificate findValue="<thumbprint>" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
             storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
          </serviceCredentials>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

make sure that you change the value  to your thumbprint of the certificate. You should also make sure that the certificate is in the correct store.

**This is just guessing from my side. Take this with a grain of salt because I have not tested it with you configuration.**

Comment: Thanks, that's great, I'll get it tested. What about the client config file?

Comment: also, what's this servicemetadata? it's not mentioned at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

thanks.

Comment: servirceMetaData: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731317(v=vs.110).aspx
You have it in your conf also, I just added httpsGetEnabled=true. About the client side: I just add a service reference to the HTTPS configuration. VS handles the rest.